# Hock rearrangement of hydroperoxides

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Which hydroperoxides undergo a Hock rearrangement?

e.g. Cumene hydroperoxide undergoes a Hock rearrangement to yield acetone and phenol

[image]

Would the following hydroperoxide of ethylbenzene also undergo any similar rearrangement? How does one decide if a Hock rearrangement is likely?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The main parts of the mechanism that will affect the rate of the reaction are the following steps (full mechanism on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumene_process#Technical_description)): abstraction of a hydrogen to form a benzylic radical and the rearrangement of the of the protonated peroxide.
These steps will be slower as they involve the formation of the higher energy species when ethylbenzene is used.

> [image: benzylic radical formation]

Secondary benzylic hydrogen have a higher bond bond dissociation energies ($357.5\: \mathrm{kJ\: mol^{-1}}$) than tertiary benzylic hydrogen ($353.3\: \mathrm{kJ\: mol^{-1}}$)$^{[1]}$. This will diminish the rate at which the initiation step proceeds, though a difference of $4.2\: \mathrm{kJ\: mol^{-1}}$ shouldn't make or break the reaction.

> [image: carbocation formation]

The formation of a primary carbocation would otherwise be highly unfavorable, except for that it is bonded to an oxygen atom. A lone pair on the oxygen can therefore be shared with the carbocation, thereby stabilizing it. This step will have a higher activation energy, but likely all that will be necessary for this reaction to occur is a little more heat and time.

---

[[1](http://chemistry.mdma.ch/hiveboard/picproxie_docs/000528883-SET-oxidation-alkylbenzenes.pdf)] Baciocchi, E.; D'acunzo, F.; Galli, C.; Lanzalunga, O. Tertiary : Secondary : Primary C–H Bond Relative Reactivity in the One-Electron Oxidation of Alkylbenzenes. A Tool to Distinguish Electron Transfer from Hydrogen Atom Transfer Mechanisms. *J. Chem. Soc.*, Perkin Trans. 2. **1996**, 133–140.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't this addressing the *formation* of the Hydroperoxide? I'm wondering if, once formed, the hydroperoxide of EB would split up or not via the Hock Rearrangement.

Comment: @curious_cat I think the second half covers what you're looking for specifically.

Comment: @curious_cat The hydroperoxide will form nearly instantly once the benzylic cation is formed. It is not part of the rate-determining step.

Comment: @ringo He is talking about the step to form the ether (the alkyl shift), after the hydroperoxide formation, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

If the image below is correct (I believe it is), then higher substitution = more stable carbocation = more likely to react this way.

[image: hock rearrangement/cumene process]

That being said, a carbocation adjacent to an oxygen atom like that is pretty stabilized, so it may not require a tertiary carbon. I'm not sure what side reactions would be promoted by a non-tertiary carbocation, though.

Comment: Actually, this picture is wrong. It applies, but not perfectly. Will fix when I'm back to my computer.